# TypeORM Tree cascade remove

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

Hi guys Im using TypeORM Materialized Tree from their docs:

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/tree-entities.md#materialized-path-aka-path-enumeration

Now I would like to Remove some Root Tree node and also to remove all of it children, Im using repository like this:

```
await repository.remove(TreeNode);
```

But Im getting cannot remove because of foreign key constraints, I passed `cascade: true` like this:

```
Column({
    length: 500,
    default: '',
  })
  name: string

@TreeParent()
  parent: Comment

  @TreeChildren({
    cascade: true,
  })
  children: Comment[]
```

But it is not taking any effect ???

Comment: Were you able to solve this? Looking for a solution myself.

Comment: Nope, I did not find a solution, change my code completely, to not use tree :/

Answer (score 1):

I think I had a similar issue. 
I got these kind of errors when I tried to remove parent entity.

After I user TreeRepostitory's findDescendants, which will populate entity's child entities, remove works fine.

> update or delete on table "mytable" violates foreign key constraint
> Key (id)=(17) is still referenced from table "mytable"

```
let treeRepo = getManager().getTreeRepository(MyEntity);
await treeRepo.findDescendants(entity)
treeRepo.remove(entity)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@TreeParent({ onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: @123木头人 Hey, welcome to SO. Can u add some explanation?

Answer (score -1):

So this answer is inspired by the previous answer from @rooste.

After I tried his solution I still faced the foreign key constrain problem, also `await treeRepo.findDescendants(entity)` was getting, well, the Descendants. Without the parent node (the entity) itself.

So I implemented the following solution (manager = getManager();)

```
 async delete(id: number) {
    const productsTree = await this.manager.getTreeRepository(ProductEntity);
    const nodeToBeDeleted = await this.manager.getTreeRepository(ProductEntity).findOne(id);
    await this.manager.query("SET foreign_key_checks = 0;");
    const res = await productsTree.remove(await productsTree.findDescendants(nodeToBeDeleted));
    await this.manager.query("SET foreign_key_checks = 1;");
    return {
      result: res.length > 0? 'Deleted successfully' : 'Already deleted'
    }
  }
```

By disabling the  foreign key constrain just temporarily and deleting the main node and its children one after another, I was able to get around this issue, but I agree with you typeORM can really suck in some cases.

I don't know if it's the best workaround in the world, so let me know if it works for you!